# Obj-c Seperate a string by double quote using regular expression

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I just learnt regular expression today and I have this NSString:

```
{"Mon":["Operation System;Monday 1,2{9-16};ProfessorA;XX-229","Database;Monday3,4{1-16};ProfessorB;XX-130","Human Computer Interaction;Monday5,6{1-8};ProfessorC;XX-130;;C Programming;Monday5,6{9-16};ProfessorC;XX-336",null,null,null]}
```

I want to separate those and put into an `NSArray` like this (after separation):

```
Mon
Operation System;Monday 1,2{9-16};ProfessorA;XX-229
Database;Monday3,4{1-16};ProfessorB;XX-130
Human Computer Interaction;Monday5,6{1-8};ProfessorC;XX-130;;C Programming;Monday5,6{9-16};ProfessorC;XX-336
```

And show that separately into my `TableViewCells`, and my regular expression is this:

```
[^\\"]
```

It does the job, but not good enough, because this made it separate into single letters instead of a string that I want. Anyone got any idea?

Comment: That looks like a JSON string.  Are you sure using regular expressions is the right way to decode it?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes that is a JSON string, unfortunately this is the best JSON I can get, so I had to use regex to parse this manually.

Comment: Is it not legal JSON then?

Comment: @trojanfoe No, but it is a JSON though, just not the way I want it to be. now I have to deal with this manually

Comment: Please add what the expected output should look like. A tip: if you want to get more than 1 character in a match, use quantifier `+` (e.g. `[^\"]+`).

Comment: @stribizhev Already edited. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The JSON is actually really close. It's much better to extract the dictionary and then make an array from the dict key and the array values (without the null items). Regex can do it but it's a strange approach to take...

Comment: you should use a proper JSON parser instead...

Comment: @Wain Thank you very much for answering. I have tried to parse the JSON using NSJSONSerialization and what I get in the TableViewCell is Mon and all the other stuff in one TableViewCell. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You'd need to show the code for that. Should be less code and more understandable than the regex pattern below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to match the text in between quotes (**EDIT**: *will capture even escaped quotes*, test includes `\\\"Monday`):

```
NSString *pattern = @"\"((?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\"";
```

Here is a sample code that can help you progress:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *pattern = @"\"((?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\"";
NSString *string = @"{\"Mon\":[\"Operation System;\\\"Monday 1,2{9-16};ProfessorA;XX-229\",\"Database;Monday3,4{1-16};ProfessorB;XX-130\",\"Human Computer Interaction;Monday5,6{1-8};ProfessorC;XX-130;;C Programming;Monday5,6{9-16};ProfessorC;XX-336\",null,null,null]}";
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:range];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
    NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"group1: %@", [string substringWithRange:group1]);
}
```

[Demo program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_objective-c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMV0dMdnY3VkpOb2s) output:

```
2015-05-14 08:45:37.906 main[33] group1: Mon                                                                                                                        
2015-05-14 08:45:37.908 main[33] group1: Operation System;\"Monday 1,2{9-16};ProfessorA;XX-229                                                                        
2015-05-14 08:45:37.908 main[33] group1: Database;Monday3,4{1-16};ProfessorB;XX-130                                                                                 
2015-05-14 08:45:37.908 main[33] group1: Human Computer Interaction;Monday5,6{1-8};ProfessorC;XX-130;;C Programming;Monday5,6{9-16};ProfessorC;XX-336
```

Comment: Now, it will also allow any escaped sequences.

Answer (score 1):

I have read the comments but I'm still slightly confused about why you do need to parse it *manually* by reg-exp, even if you get it as string...

so, I present this, it may be useful (if not for you, but for someone who does not want to create an actual reg-exp but wants to parse it generally):

```
NSString *_json = @"{\"Mon\":[\"Operation System;Monday 1,2{9-16};ProfessorA;XX-229\",\"Database;Monday3,4{1-16};ProfessorB;XX-130\",\"Human Computer Interaction;Monday5,6{1-8};ProfessorC;XX-130;;C Programming;Monday5,6{9-16};ProfessorC;XX-336\",null,null,null]}";
NSError *_error = nil;
id _jsonId = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[_json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&_error];
```

then you can do whatever you'd like to do with the values actually, because `_jsonId` looks like the this:

```
{
    Mon =     (
        "Operation System;Monday 1,2{9-16};ProfessorA;XX-229",
        "Database;Monday3,4{1-16};ProfessorB;XX-130",
        "Human Computer Interaction;Monday5,6{1-8};ProfessorC;XX-130;;C Programming;Monday5,6{9-16};ProfessorC;XX-336",
        "<null>",
        "<null>",
        "<null>"
    );
}
```

---

and you can extract the values *manually* like e.g.:

```
NSArray *_keyMon = [_jsonId valueForKey:@"Mon"];

NSString *_value0 = [_keyMon objectAtIndex:0]; // Operation System;Monday 1,2{9-16};ProfessorA;XX-229
NSString *_value1 = [_keyMon objectAtIndex:1]; // Database;Monday3,4{1-16};ProfessorB;XX-130
NSString *_value1 = [_keyMon objectAtIndex:2]; // Human Computer Interaction;Monday5,6{1-8};ProfessorC;XX-130;;C Programming;Monday5,6{9-16};ProfessorC;XX-336
// 3, 4, etc...
NSString *_value5 = [_keyMon objectAtIndex:5];
```

---

which values may need further post-processing, to separate the components by `;`, like:

```
NSArray *_value0Components = [_value0 componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

which will contain:

```
(
    "Operation System",
    "Monday 1,2{9-16}",
    "ProfessorA",
    "XX-229"
)
```

etc...

Comment: Yes that does help me... If only I could select two correct answers... again, thank you very much for answering. I can really use this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like perfectly fine JSON to me and to everyone else. Trying to parse it with regular expressions is sheer madness. JSON will give you a nice dictionary, with an array of strings and NSNull values under the key "Mon". You couldn't ask for anything better.

(The answer using regular expressions won't handle escaped characters, will lose numbers, booleans, null values, and loses the structure, so once you've got keys "Mon" and "Tue" you are stuck).

And really, knowing how to parse JSON is an absolute must for any programmer nowadays, so you better get used to it.

Comment: Yes and thanks for answering. I tried to parse this JSON using NSJSONSerialization, and what I get is Mon and everything else in the same TableViewCell. Did I do something wrong?